# Link active when being clicked at the second time

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have some tricky condition about my menu navigation in Mobile Site.
Just said, I has this kind of Menu Navigation in my site:

Menu : Test (link to : www.test.com)

Submenu : -Test1 (link to : www.test.com/test1)

Submenu : -Test2 (link to : www.test.com/test2)

Submenu : -Test3 (link to : www.test.com/test3)

The "Test" menu used toogle jquery feature, so when we clicked at Test, it will activate the toggle feature and show the sub-menu "Test1,Test2 and Test3"

But how about if the "Test" menu already has a link inside of it (link to : www.test.com), so when we intend to toggle the Menu by clicking the "Test" Menu, it will caused the site to go to www.test.com.

Anyone have idea to overcome this condition?
Sorry for the bad English or illustration.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for that

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tg2uz/

```
<a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$( "<div>" )
.append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
.appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>
```